# MySQL: How does groupby work on columns without aggregate functions?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am somewhat confused about how the `group by` command works in mysql.

Suppose I have a table:

```
mysql> select recordID, IPAddress, date, httpMethod from Log_Analysis_Records_dalhousieShort;                   
+----------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| recordID | IPAddress       | date                | httpMethod                                      |
+----------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|        1 | 64.68.88.22     | 2003-07-09 00:00:21 | GET /news/science/cancer.shtml HTTP/1.0         | 
|        2 | 64.68.88.166    | 2003-07-09 00:00:55 | GET /news/internet/xml.shtml HTTP/1.0           | 
|        3 | 129.173.177.214 | 2003-07-09 00:01:23 | GET / HTTP/1.1                                  | 
|        4 | 129.173.177.214 | 2003-07-09 00:01:23 | GET /include/fcs_style.css HTTP/1.1             | 
|        5 | 129.173.177.214 | 2003-07-09 00:01:23 | GET /include/main_page.css HTTP/1.1             | 
|        6 | 129.173.177.214 | 2003-07-09 00:01:23 | GET /images/bigportaltopbanner.gif HTTP/1.1     | 
|        7 | 129.173.177.214 | 2003-07-09 00:01:23 | GET /images/right_1.jpg HTTP/1.1                | 
|        8 | 64.68.88.165    | 2003-07-09 00:02:43 | GET /studentservices/responsible.shtml HTTP/1.0 | 
|        9 | 64.68.88.165    | 2003-07-09 00:02:44 | GET /news/sports/basketball.shtml HTTP/1.0      | 
|       10 | 64.68.88.34     | 2003-07-09 00:02:46 | GET /news/science/space.shtml HTTP/1.0          | 
|       11 | 129.173.159.98  | 2003-07-09 00:03:46 | GET / HTTP/1.1                                  | 
|       12 | 129.173.159.98  | 2003-07-09 00:03:46 | GET /include/fcs_style.css HTTP/1.1             | 
|       13 | 129.173.159.98  | 2003-07-09 00:03:46 | GET /include/main_page.css HTTP/1.1             | 
|       14 | 129.173.159.98  | 2003-07-09 00:03:48 | GET /images/bigportaltopbanner.gif HTTP/1.1     | 
|       15 | 129.173.159.98  | 2003-07-09 00:03:48 | GET /images/left_1g.jpg HTTP/1.1                | 
|       16 | 129.173.159.98  | 2003-07-09 00:03:48 | GET /images/webcam.gif HTTP/1.1                 | 
+----------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

---

When I am execute this statement how does it choose which `recordID` to include since there are a range of `recordID`s that would be correct?  Does it just choose the first one that matches?

```
mysql> select recordID, IPAddress, date, httpMethod from Log_Analysis_Records_dalhousieShort GROUP BY IPADDRESS;
+----------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| recordID | IPAddress       | date                | httpMethod                                      |
+----------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|       11 | 129.173.159.98  | 2003-07-09 00:03:46 | GET / HTTP/1.1                                  | 
|        3 | 129.173.177.214 | 2003-07-09 00:01:23 | GET / HTTP/1.1                                  | 
|        8 | 64.68.88.165    | 2003-07-09 00:02:43 | GET /studentservices/responsible.shtml HTTP/1.0 | 
|        2 | 64.68.88.166    | 2003-07-09 00:00:55 | GET /news/internet/xml.shtml HTTP/1.0           | 
|        1 | 64.68.88.22     | 2003-07-09 00:00:21 | GET /news/science/cancer.shtml HTTP/1.0         | 
|       10 | 64.68.88.34     | 2003-07-09 00:02:46 | GET /news/science/space.shtml HTTP/1.0          | 
+----------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

For this table the `max(date)` and `min(date)` values seem logical to me but I am confused about how the `recordID` and `httpMethod` where chosen.

Is it safe use two aggregate functions in one command?

```
mysql> select recordID, IPAddress, min(date), max(date), httpMethod from Log_Analysis_Records_dalhousieShort GROUP BY IPADDRESS;
+----------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| recordID | IPAddress       | min(date)           | max(date)           | httpMethod                                      |
+----------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|       11 | 129.173.159.98  | 2003-07-09 00:03:46 | 2003-07-09 00:03:48 | GET / HTTP/1.1                                  | 
|        3 | 129.173.177.214 | 2003-07-09 00:01:23 | 2003-07-09 00:01:23 | GET / HTTP/1.1                                  | 
|        8 | 64.68.88.165    | 2003-07-09 00:02:43 | 2003-07-09 00:02:44 | GET /studentservices/responsible.shtml HTTP/1.0 | 
|        2 | 64.68.88.166    | 2003-07-09 00:00:55 | 2003-07-09 00:00:55 | GET /news/internet/xml.shtml HTTP/1.0           | 
|        1 | 64.68.88.22     | 2003-07-09 00:00:21 | 2003-07-09 00:00:21 | GET /news/science/cancer.shtml HTTP/1.0         | 
|       10 | 64.68.88.34     | 2003-07-09 00:02:46 | 2003-07-09 00:02:46 | GET /news/science/space.shtml HTTP/1.0          | 
+----------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Usually use of GROUP BY while listing a field in the select expression without an aggregate function is invalid SQL and should throw an error.

MySQL, however, allows this and simply chooses one value randomly. Try to avoid it, because it is confusing.

To disallow this, you can say at runtime:

`SET sql_mode := CONCAT('ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,',@@sql_mode);`

or use the configuration value and/or command line option `sql-mode`.

Yes, listing two aggregate functions is completely valid.

Comment: To be clear, it's not actually **random**. If you execute the same query against an unchanging table repeatedly, you'll get the same results every time. But changing the table (even in ways that would not otherwise be visible in the query results) may cause a different value to come up.

Comment: is there a way I can set mysql to strict mode or something similar to disallow this behavior?

Comment: @VoteyDisciple I should have written "undefined".

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Edited the answer.

Comment: You could just set the SQL mode to "traditional" using `SET SESSION sql_mode = 'TRADITIONAL';`

Comment: @Hammerite With mysql 5.5.46, setting mode to traditional didn't work, but setting it to only_full_group_by did work.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong, only_full_group_by isn't part of traditional, I don't know why not.

Comment: How do you 'unset' this behaviour? :)

Comment: If you really want to: `SET SESSION sql_mode = REPLACE(@@sql_mode,"ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY","")`

Answer (score 5):

Because I'm new apparently I can't post helpful images so I'll try to do this with text...

I just tested this and it appears that the values of fields that are NOT in the GROUP BY will use the values of the FIRST row that matches the group by condition. This will also explain the perceived "randomness" that others have experienced with selecting columns that aren't in a group by clause.

Example:

Create a table called "test" with 2 columns called "col1" and "col2" with data that looks like this:

Col1 Col2
1 2
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 1
3 2
3 3

Then run the following query:

*select col1,col2
from test
order by col2 **desc***

You will get this result:

**1 3

2 3

3 3**

1 2
1 2
2 2
3 2
2 1
3 1

Now consider the following query:

*select groupTable.col1,groupTable.col2

from (

   select col1,col2

   from test

   order by col2 **desc**

) groupTable

group by groupTable.col1 

order by groupTable.col1 desc*

You will get this result:

3 3
2 3
1 3

Change the subquery to asc:

*select col1,col2
from test
order by col2 **asc***

Result:

**2 1

3 1

1 2**

1 2
2 2
3 2
1 3
2 3
3 3

Again use that as the basis for your subquery:

*select groupTable.col1,groupTable.col2

from (

   select col1,col2

   from test

   order by col2 **asc**

) groupTable

group by groupTable.col1 

order by groupTable.col1 desc*

Result:
3 1
2 1
1 2

Now you should be able to see how the order of the subquery affects which values are chosen for fields that are selected but not in the group by clause.  This would explain the perceived "randomness" that others have mentioned because if the subquery (or lack there of) is not combined with an ORDER BY clause then mysql will grab rows as they come in, but by defining a sort order in a subquery you are able to control this behavior and get predictable results.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it takes the first row according to the PRIMARY KEY or any INDEX, because it looks like it works that way, but i've tried a GROUP BY query on various tables and didn't identify any pattern.

Therefore i will avoid to use any value of non-grouped columns.

Answer (score 0):

Group By picks up the first record based on the index. Let us say Log_Analysis_Records_dalhousieShort table has recoedID as index. Hence, group by picked 11 recordID for IPAddress 129.173.159.98 among recordID 11 to 16. However min and max are pre group by operations in a way so there values are computed logically for you.

```
mysql> select recordID, IPAddress, date, httpMethod from Log_Analysis_Records_dalhousieShort GROUP BY IPADDRESS;
+----------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| recordID | IPAddress       | date                | httpMethod                                      |
+----------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|       11 | 129.173.159.98  | 2003-07-09 00:03:46 | GET / HTTP/1.1                                  | 
|        3 | 129.173.177.214 | 2003-07-09 00:01:23 | GET / HTTP/1.1                                  | 
|        8 | 64.68.88.165    | 2003-07-09 00:02:43 | GET /studentservices/responsible.shtml HTTP/1.0 | 
|        2 | 64.68.88.166    | 2003-07-09 00:00:55 | GET /news/internet/xml.shtml HTTP/1.0           | 
|        1 | 64.68.88.22     | 2003-07-09 00:00:21 | GET /news/science/cancer.shtml HTTP/1.0         | 
|       10 | 64.68.88.34     | 2003-07-09 00:02:46 | GET /news/science/space.shtml HTTP/1.0          | 
+----------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```